# Query to get date of every Sunday & Saturday in Hive or Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hive, hiveql

I'd like to get dates of all Sundays & Saturdays in Hive from a given date.
For example, if the given date is 2020-10-01, it needs to return two rows sunday_dates, saturday_dates with values of all Sundays & Saturdays after that date "2020-10-01".

I tried something like this but, seems not working for me.

```
spark.sql("select date_sub('2020-10-01', cast(date_format(current_date(),'u')%7 as int)) as sunday_dates").show(10,False)
+------------+
|sunday_dates|
+------------+
|2020-09-29  |
+------------+
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Hive or pyspark.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please help upvote the solution in case if this helped you .. Will really appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`date_trunc()`** in order reach the week start date Post that **`date_sub()`** and **`date_sub()`** in order to get the Saturday and Sunday

## Create the dataframe here

```
    df = spark.createDataFrame([("2020-11-02",1),("2020-11-03",2),("2020-11-04",3)],["event_dt","word"])
    df.show()
    df = df.withColumn("week_start", F.date_trunc('WEEK', F.col("event_dt")))
#`In case you want to get backward weekdays`
    df = df.selectExpr('*', 'date_sub(week_start, 2) as backward_Saturday')
    df = df.selectExpr('*', 'date_sub(week_start, 1) as backward_Sunday')
# In case you want forward weekends
    df = df.selectExpr('*', 'date_add(week_start, 5) as forward_Saturday')
    df = df.selectExpr('*', 'date_add(week_start, 6) as forward_Sunday')
    df.show()
```

## Input

```
+----------+----+
|  event_dt|word|
+----------+----+
|2020-11-02|   1|
|2020-11-03|   2|
|2020-11-04|   3|
+----------+----+
```

## Output

```
+----------+----+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
|  event_dt|word|         week_start|backward_Saturday|backward_Sunday|forward_Saturday|forward_Sunday|
+----------+----+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
|2020-11-02|   1|2020-11-02 00:00:00|       2020-10-31|     2020-11-01|      2020-11-07|    2020-11-08|
|2020-11-03|   2|2020-11-02 00:00:00|       2020-10-31|     2020-11-01|      2020-11-07|    2020-11-08|
|2020-11-04|   3|2020-11-02 00:00:00|       2020-10-31|     2020-11-01|      2020-11-07|    2020-11-08|
+----------+----+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
```